# Reading Date Time in R (01.01.2019 00:00)

Tags: r, dataset, data

How do you read a date in R that is given in the following way:

01.01.2019 00:00

While reading it with `read.csv("my_file.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",")` I am getting the date column as a "factor" class. I am tring to figure how to read this data time data as a date. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method (assuming that 'time' is the column you want, and the date format is Date.Month.Year Hour:Minute):

```
d <- read.csv("my_file.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",")
strptime(as.character(d$time), format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library `readr`, part of the tidyverse.

```
my_data<- read_delim("my_file.csv", delim = ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_types = cols(date = col_datetime(format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")), 
    locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","), 
    trim_ws = TRUE)
```